# Opening URL throws String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Using AngleSharp v 0.9.9.0 this:

```
var siteUrl = "https://richmond.csod.com/ats/careersite/search.aspx?site=1&c=richmond";

var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies();
var currentContext = BrowsingContext.New(configuration);
var originalDoc = currentContext.OpenAsync(siteUrl).Result;

Console.WriteLine(originalDoc.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);
```

Works fine. But if I upgrade to v 0.9.9.2 it throws this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at AngleSharp.Services.Default.MemoryCookieProvider.Sanatize(String cookie)
   at AngleSharp.Services.Default.MemoryCookieProvider.SetCookie(String origin, String value)
   at AngleSharp.Dom.Document.set_Cookie(String value)
   at AngleSharp.Dom.Document.Setup(CreateDocumentOptions options)
   at AngleSharp.Dom.Html.HtmlDocument.<LoadAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AngleSharp.BrowsingContextExtensions.<OpenAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at AngleSharpTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\matt.burland\source\repos\AngleSharpTest\AngleSharpTest\Program.cs:line 21
```

It seems to be coming internally from AngleSharp and happens for several different, completely unrelated urls. FWIW, my culture settings are `en-US`, and I've tried setting to invariant culture but that doesn't seem to help either.

Has anybody else seen this problem? Is there a work around?

Comment: are you try without ".WithCookies()" ?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine without the `.WithCookies`, but I need to have cookie support (not at this point, but further down the line with some form submissions)

Comment: Workaround is to roll your own cookie provider.